# processes vs threads (user vs kernel)

Tags: c, multithreading, process, pthreads

I understand the difference between a process and a thread. And I know the difference between a user thread and a kernel thread.

**Question**

How do you code any of them in C? All I know in C is how to create POSIX threads, but is this user threads or kernel threads?

Can anyone put some C code samples for a process, user thread and a kernel thread.

Are there any type of threads that I did not include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to this mostly depends on your operating system.  POSIX threads can be implemented as either user threads or kernel threads - it is just an API specification.  On any modern Linux system, they are implemented with kernel threads.

In terms of lower-level APIs, the UNIX system call `fork()` creates a new process.  On Linux, the system call `clone()` can be used to create a new kernel thread (by passing the `CLONE_VM` flag) - other operating systems will have other calls to do this.  Creation of a user thread will depend entirely on what user threading library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html) that should help with threads. You can use a different attr parameter to pthread_create to choose user vs kernel.

For processes, try the [fork tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html).